# ediff show empty lines

Tags: ediff

I'm not sure how to describe this. In vimdiff I remember that if one of the buffers had added a line, the other buffer showed lines at that same vertical location to show where they were added. I found a picture that shows what I mean:

[image: vimdiff]

On the other hand, in ediff the space is not taken up on the left buffer, instead there's a single character highlighted in that buffer as shown below.

[image]

*Above picture is cropped from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yISBA.png).*

Perhaps I'll get used to this way of showing things, but in any case I'm curious if it's possible to configure ediff to show things like vimdiff does.

**EDIT**: To anyone who's interested, it seems there's a package that emulates this now: https://github.com/justbur/emacs-vdiff

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I think you'll get used to it. ;-)